TF1 SSD Mobilenet v2, TF2 SSD Mobilenet mAP difference
I'm training an object detection model using the SSD Mobilenetv2 model with the same data (using the same tfrecord files) using both TF1 and TF2. The batch size, number of epochs, GPU used, and all other values are the same. I'm also using the same files provided here as the pipeline.config file;https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/configs. However, even after retraining the model several times, I'm getting a higher mAP value with TF1 compared to TF2. The results are as follows: I achieve a 72% mAP with TF1 and a 49% mAP with TF2. What could be the reason for this discrepancy?
